# Multiple NSbutton tracking hover while mouse down

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton, nscontrol

I want to create a similar row of buttons like in Xcodes Utilities side panel (see image).

[image: XcodeUtilitiesButtons]

I'ts easy to just add four Image buttons beside each other. But, there's one feature that I haven't solved yet.

If you press and hold on one of the buttons, you can hover (while holding down the mouse) between any of the buttons, then each buttons alternate image gets shown if the mouse is hovering over it, and when you let go that button is selected.

I haven't found any default element that supplies this, so I've been tinkering with different solutions.

I would need to subclass **NSButton** to catch the **-mouseDown** event and create my own event tracking loop, so that's clear. And from that I should be able to check where the mouse is pointing (while the button is pressed down) and just call the button it's pointing to and set it's alternate image to show.

My idea was to create an **NSView** that would hold the buttons, so that it could handle the checking of the mouse point and in turn call all the buttons.

But with that approach I'm stuck at trying to find the button's place in the view. I've added a **IBOutlet** to the button and if I call the buttons **-frame** from my view I always get 0 as the result:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect([_button frame]));
{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
```

I've tried all variations of **convertRect:toView** and **convertRect:fromView** I can think of without any result. (as I don't get a valid output from the button's **-frame** call).

So, I have two questions:

1. Is this a valid approach, If not, what would be a better solution?
2. How can I get the button's position inside my custom view (the Buttons superview) to know if the mouse is hovering over the button.

I'm currently doing this (with the BOOL isInsideButton check not working.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    BOOL keepOn = YES;
    BOOL isInsideView = YES;
    BOOL isInsideButton = YES;
    NSPoint mouseLoc;

    while (keepOn) {
        theEvent = [[self window] nextEventMatchingMask: NSLeftMouseUpMask |
                NSLeftMouseDraggedMask];
        mouseLoc = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
        isInsideView = [self mouse:mouseLoc inRect:[self bounds]];
        isInsideButton = [self mouse:mouseLoc inRect:[self.superview convertRect:[_buttonOne frame] toView:self]];
    };
    return;
}
```